# Creating a custom template page in wordpress causing other features to stop working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and i'm trying to create a custom template. I'm using the default twentyfifteen theme. I went to `wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen` and copied `page.php` to a new file called `page_with-contact.php` and added this comment on the top :

```
/*
Template Name: Page with contact
*/
```

I made no other changes to the template. 
I then went to the admin site and changed one of the pages to "page with contact".

When I open the page I see that the affix on the left menu is not working and the responsive menu is not working either.

I followed a pretty simple tutorial here so I'm just wondering what am I doing wrong.

**EDIT**

Following @masiorama's answer and the comments below is crated a child theme, moved the template file to the child theme and renamed it to `page-with-contact.php`, This is the content of the template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page with contact
*/

get_header(); ?>

  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main my-content-page" role="main">

    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

      // Include the page content template.
      get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

      // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    ?>
      <div class="hentry entry-content contact-form">
        <?php
          echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="19" title="contact form 1"]');
        ?>
      </div>
    <?php
    // End the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->
  </div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php
  get_sidebar();
  get_footer();
?>
```

Now I have several problems :

1. As you can see the sidebar, heading and footer are all included but the affix and responsive menu are still not working.
2. The contact form (which previously worked fine) is now not showing at all.
3. I'm unable to enqueue the parent's `rtl.css` file.

Appreciate any further guidance.

Comment: You should use child themes to modify anything from a theme. Other wise you can not update your theme or you lose the changes. check this out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes Then do the changes on the child theme.

Comment: Hey, I updated the question. Please take another look.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know your page file should be named:

```
page-with-contact.php
```

and not:

```
page_with-contact.php
```

Be sure that it contains at least some wordpress function calls like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- stuff -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Check this for more details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: Hey, updated the question after adding those tags and still no change.

Comment: I didn't suggest you to create a child theme (even if it is good practice) so I will leave the comments to those problems (point 3) to @Abel. Problems 1 and 2 are related to how you include the parts (form and menu). Where is form shortcode defined? Can you show the live project? I sense we are blaming the wrong part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Need this WordPress hooke to call in your template

```html
   

get_header();
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling  a template within a template. '`get_template_part( 'content', 'page' )`;' should be `the_content();`. Good chance that's whats messing you around.

Comment: Thanks @Gavin, But it just added the page content (Without the header not any markup) so this is not what i'm after here. Thanks.

Comment: That's doesn't quite make sense, unless you deleted 'get_header();' etc from your template?

Comment: I copied `page.php` without changing anything. I just renamed the file to immeitate a custom template. I have no idea what am i doing wrong here and why the responsive menu and the affix menu are not working.

Comment: Ok then... next! Taking a look at the code you posted, you contact form is going to be included for each and every post, yet has the same 'id'. Move the contact form below the 'endwhile' line at the end of the loop, just before `</main>`. I must add when I work with custom templates the page to copy is "single.php" and "archive.php", not "page.php". Maybe try copying those files instead to your own "single-with-contact.php" and "archive-with-contact" and remove "page-with-contact.php".

Comment: Thanks @Gavin, I removed all the page-* from my child template and copied `single.php` as you suggested from the original theme to my child theme and called it `single-with-contact`. The responsive menu is still not working and so does the affix. Do you have any idea what can possibly go wrong in this simple process ?

Comment: Hmm. My guess is one of your other plugins conflicting with it. Try disabling plugins and see if it makes any difference. I am currently using the twentyfifteen theme quite a bit, with custom templates, and don't have much of a problem, but one plugin is messing around with the layout which I haven't looked at yet. I think it would be best to check if it's a plugin causing a problem so you don;t spend the rest of your life looking for a problem with your custom template :). (Just 'cos it's a plugin does not mean it's not a problem in all circumstances).

Comment: Well, I haven't really installed any plugins other then contact-7 so it seem a bit strange that it would mess with the layout. But, i'm mostly developing in python so judging by the horror stories i heard about PHP I guess it's possible ...

Comment: Lol. php horror stories, nah!. As  Masiorama commented below, we are perhaps looking at the wrong part of the code then. I just can't do else to help much at the moment as I'm a bit busy :/

Comment: Thanks man. I think i found the problem - I'm inheriting the styles but not the JS files (You would expect that template inheritance would do that for you but guess not ... ). Now I just need to figure out what is the proper way to load *all* the parent's js files.

Comment: Cool, keep going. It's one way to learn all about wordpress :)

Comment: PS, only load what you need for your custom template, eg `wp_enqueue_script('schs_forum', schs_forum::get_plugin_directory() . '/js/schs-forum.js', array('jquery'));`